# Validating email addres with specific ending rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a field to a model I just added. My problem is that if I make the field a string, then it limits the field to 157 characters or some ridiculous number. Is there something bigger I could use that would give me a field that could potentially contain a ton of text in it.

Comment: In questions like this you must specify the database you are using

Answer (score 1):

Make it a "text" field? Unlimited in length

Comment: Can I assign text to it? So do email:text when I make the model?

Comment: It functions exactly the same as a string field, except that it has no limitation. In your migration you indeed specify it as "text"